# android clicking debug chooses release variant

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio, when I click the "debug" icon in the tool bar, gradle is appearing to try to make a release build.

First, it shows me the "edit configuration" popup. At the bottom, it has a message "the apk for your currently selected variant (app-release-unsigned.apk) is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant (release).

Why is it trying to use "release" when I click "debug"? Obviously I changed something, I wish I knew what...

Here's my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.perinote.camera"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24

        renderscriptTargetApi 20
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by deleting the .idea directory. After it was regenerated, my builds were correctly produced.

I also completely removed and reinstalled Android Studio and the SDK. However, the debug build was still messed up after that.